# How do you remove Chrome and references to MyWay

Tags: google-chrome

I want to remove Remove Search.myway.com from my Chrome browser.  So I removed the Chrome browser from my Ubuntu 16.04 and then installed it again.

Sad to say, the new installation of Chrome was still using Search.myway.com...

Anybody have ideas on how to remove Search.myway.com from Chrome?

I would guess I could format the hard drive and re-install Ubuntu 16.04 again, but that seems to be pretty drastic.

I have been searching for a way to do this, but so far non of the methods I have found work for me.

Help and thanks.... :-(

Comment: Can you go to "Settings" > "Search" > "Manage search engines..." > "Default search settings" and remove myway?

Comment: look in extensions too - also remember that uninstalling a program doesn't purge the settings files - try using the "purge" option - `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable`

Answer (score 2):

I have Ubuntu 14.04.  I seem to have rid Chrome of Myway by 
setting Google as my default search engine and deleting all other search options.  Now when I open another Chrome tab I see a Google search argument window.  Myway is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply delete the Chrome data directory, which is located in `~/.config/google-chrome/`. To delete it, open a terminal and type

```
rm -r .config/google-chrome
```

Note that this will delete *all* data you have in Chrome, including bookmarks, history, as well as that search engine you want to get rid of.

A less drastic possibility might be to simply remove MyWay within chrome, to do that, go to "Settings" > "Search" > "Manage search engines..." > "Default search settings", and remove it there, have you tried that ?

Comment: I tried doing "Settings" > "Search" > "Manage search engines..." > "Default search settings"... and it does not work.    no option for "Search.myway.com" exist to in the lists of search engines to manage.  I will try to do rm -r .config/google-chrome and post the results.

Comment: I tried rm -r .config/google-chrome and it didn't work.  I thought it worked, but after about 1 minute, as I was going though the steps of specifying my email address for Chrome to use, I got the "Search.myway.com" page as my default search page.  It is looking more and more like the solution to this is to "reformat my hard drive and re-install Ubuntu 16.04 from scratch."  The people that are installing myway on my system are really a pain in the ASS.  Maybe everybody having this problem should start a class action suit against them.

Comment: For the time being I will just use Firefox.  It has not been corrupted.  (*&(*&&

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to remove this myway thing - maybe try clearing your cache in chrome as well and make sure you're not installing any chrome extensions which may be doing this. (Even seemingly legitimate ones sometimes do things like this) Could also be some other software which you installed in Ubuntu which is setting the Chrome homepage in order to make some money. But if Firefox works for you, great. @ElmerFittery

Answer (score 0):

I see junk from MyWay on my customers' Windows PCs all the time. The simplest solution is to reset Chrome, then remove unwanted extensions.

1. Open Chrome
2. Go to **Settings**
3. Search for "reset"
4. Reset Chrome
5. Go to **Extensions**
6. Remove extensions you don't want
7. Enable extensions you do want

Sources and more detail:

1. [Reset Chrome settings to default](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en)
2. [Install and manage extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en)

Note that reinstalling Chrome, on Ubuntu and Windows alike, does not remove its config.